# Linking .a file in Makefile

Tags: c, unix, makefile, linker

How can I add a .a library into my Makefile?

For example, if I have ../mylib/mylib.a, what do I have to write into the Makefile in order for it to include all the code in mylib.a?

Sorry, Makefiles are very new to me.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I presume you want to link that library into an executable. Do you know how to do it manually on the command line? If so then it's the same command option in the Makefile. If not, then you need to learn that first. If you need help with a specific Makefile then you need to show what you have so far.

Answer (score -1):

(Supposing mylib.a and mylib.h are on the same ../mylib/ path)

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -O3 -Wall

LIB = mylib
LIB_PATH = ../mylib/

PROGRAM = myprogram
...

all:
    ...
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(LIB_PATH) -L$(LIB_PATH) -o $(PROGRAM) main.c  -l$(LIB) `pkg-config ...`
```

Basically, you need set the include path to the .h file with -I, then -L for the lib path and -l to set the lib name.